# Get XSLT global variable as test for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, variables, xslt, binding, cross-browser

I'm new to the world of XSLT, I only know the basics. I am trying to modify some files to work on Chrome (at the moment they work only on IE). One if the issues I have now is in this section:

```
<td class="2k3ButtonContainer">
  <div id="coolTheme" style="height:20px;direction:rtl;background:URL('../../Assets/UI/Images/{$name}.gif') no-repeat 100% 0px;padding-right:20px;"         dir="rtl" class="2k3Button" onclick="{$onclick}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$caption"/>
      <xsl:if test="$hasDown='1'">
        <img src="../../Assets/UI/Images/Splash/arrow.down.gif" align="absmiddle" style="width:7px;height:4px;margin:0 2 0 2"/>
      </xsl:if>
  </div>
</td>
```

The line `<xsl:value-of select="$caption"/>` that should replace the text of the div isn't working for Chrome. The variable exists, I know it because `$name` and `$onclick` are correct, but when placed in the `div` as text I cannot get the value of the caption variable. (I get the buttons with the correct images and events, but without labels).
I tried to read about it, but I am not sure what to look for, and I didn't understand the little info I found about it.

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT variable references are tricky. Try referencing it the long way instead:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/xsl:variable/@select[../@name='caption']"/>
```